# Finding point(s) of intersection between $f(x)= \cos (2x)$ and $g(x)=- \cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the point(s) of intersection between $f(x)= \cos (2x)$ and $g(x)=- \cos x$, over interval $(0,2 \pi)$. Verify by graphing.

Comment: This is the **raw text** of your homework. Are you able to add some words of your own ? Say what you have done. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed...

Comment: Can you use the identity for cos(2x)

Comment: I did! $cos(2x)=2cos^2(x)-1$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Remember you can accept an answer using the green tick by the answer you would like to choose!

Answer (score 2):

All we need to do is set them equal to each other! So $\cos(2x)=-\cos(x)$. Then rearrange to $\cos(2x)+\cos(x)=0$ then change that to $2\cos^2(x)+\cos(x)-1=0$. Which is a quadratic equation which we get $\cos(x)= -1$ and $\cos(x)= \frac{1}{2}$.

So we get the general solutions $x=2n\pi+ \pi$, $x=\frac{5\pi}{3}+2n\pi$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi$

As for graphing you can use Desmos, or try and plot these graphs yourself and see where they intersect!

Edit: Graph for interest which backs up our claim!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start of a solution... the graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity $\cos p+\cos q=2\cos(\frac{p+q}2)\cos(\frac{p-q}2)$,

$$\cos 2x+\cos x=2\cos(\frac32x)\cos(\frac12x)$$

This is zero iff $\frac32x=\frac\pi2+k\pi$ or $\frac12x=\frac\pi2+k\pi$, that is if $x=\frac\pi3+\frac{2k\pi}3$ or $x=\pi+2k\pi$, for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

You want the values in $(0,2\pi)$, so

$$x\in\{\frac\pi3,\pi,\frac{5\pi}{3}\}$$

Comment: Thank you, but isn't 5π/3 also admissable??

Comment: @DevrshiModi-CentralPeelSS My bad! Thanks, it's corrected now.